# Using sqlite virtual tables with SqlJet

Tags: java, sqlite, sqljet

I'm using the SqlJet Java SqlLite library. I've created a virtual table and now would like to insert rows into it. However, the only insert method I can find applies to a table ojbect, not a virtual table. When I attempt to access the virtual table as a table:

```
ISqlJetVirtualTableDef vtd =
     db.createVirtualTable(props.getProperty("CREATE_VIRTUAL_TABLE_QUERY"));
String virtual_table_name = vtd.getTableName();
ISqlJetTable table = db.getTable(virtual_table_name);
table.insert( etc. )
```

the db.getTable(table_name) method throws a "table not found" error. This might be expected, but I don't know what other approach to take.